# Json parsing problem android 

Tags: android, android-layout

If the response of a request is a json response how to handle it and decode it.I have tried the following abnd get an error @     JSONArray json = new JSONArray(r1);

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);  
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

String r1 = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
System.out.println("printing response now "+r1);
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(r1);


//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data received"+r1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(r1);
JSONArray venues = json.getJSONObject("data")
          .getJSONArray("url")
          .getJSONObject(0)
          .getJSONArray("url");
```

Json structure is given below

```
 [
 {"data": 
  {"url": 
   {
     "url": "http://www.xxxxxx.com/story.html", "title":"some data","source_url": "www.somesite.com", "summary": "\n \n \n \n \n somedata again"
   }
  }
 }
 ]
```

Error:

```
   08-18 16:30:22.907: INFO/System.out(1178): Exceptionorg.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: could you post the error you get?

Comment: your sample json text file show a Array object at first.. but your code request object and not an array. See answer below

Comment: JSONArray(r1); isok ... JSONObject(r1); not ok ... then replace JSONObject(r1); by JSONArray(r1); ... then do not forget that you access a array , you've to adapt "venues" code part accordingly.

Comment: I've made a code to check same context with your json sample .. and it works for me .. see answer

Comment: I will let u know about this and the entire code..Please await for my questions..

Answer (score 0):

I've this following code taking your json and it works for me...
May be you've to check if your orginal json string is ok ... byte per byte may be .. invisible character may disturb the parsing

```
  String r1 = "[{\"data\": {\"url\": { \"url\": \"http://www.xxxxxx.com/story.html\",  \"title\":\"some data\",\"source_url\": \"www.somesite.com\", \"summary\": \"\\n \\n \\n \\n \\n somedata again\"}}}]";
try {
   JSONArray json = new JSONArray(r1);

   Object url = json.getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONObject("data")
            .getJSONObject("url")
            .get("url");
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "url="+url.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   Log.i("TESTJSON","All Is Ok");

} catch (Exception e) {
   Log.d("TESTJSON","Something wrong..",e);
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Yes i did change that but the problem arises with this statement,JSONObject json = new JSONObject(r1);

Comment: Should there be aspecific  mimetype associated on the server side on sending the response

Comment: No that was a mistake the code is actually crashing in JSONObject json = new JSONObject(r1);  i have corrected that in the question

Comment: Sorry if u see my edit JSONArray json = new JSONArray(r1); gives an error as well.....Please ignore my previous comment